# Assign additional labels to a string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a dictionary to assign labels to sentences. Currently, it works well on a single label. But there're situations they could have one more labels. How can I do this from a string-search approach?

```
import pandas as pd

entertainment_dict = {
  "Food": ["McDonald", "Five Guys", "KFC"],
  "Music": ["Taylor Swift", "Jay Z", "One Direction"],
  "TV": ["Big Bang Theory", "Queen of South", "Ted Lasso"]
}

data = {'text':["Kevin Lee has bought a Taylor Swift's CD and eaten at McDonald.", 
                "The best burger in McDonald is cheeze buger.",
                "Kevin Lee is planning to watch the Big Bang Theory and eat at KFC."]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

regex = '|'.join(f'(?P<{k}>{"|".join(v)})' for k,v in entertainment_dict.items())
df['labels'] = ((df['text'].str.extract(regex).notnull()*entertainment_dict.keys())
                 .apply(lambda r: ','.join([i for i in r if i]) , axis=1)
                )
                                                text labels
0  Kevin Lee has bought a Taylor Swift's CD and e...  Music
1       The best burger in McDonald is cheeze buger.   Food
2  Kevin Lee is planning to watch the Big Bang Th...     TV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `extract` into `extractall` and join the matches with `groupby`:

```
regex = '|'.join(f'(?P<{k}>{"|".join(v)})' for k,v in entertainment_dict.items())
df['labels'] = ((df['text'].str.extractall(regex).notnull().groupby(level=0).max()*entertainment_dict.keys())
                 .apply(lambda r: ','.join([i for i in r if i]) , axis=1)
                )
```

In summary, change `df['text'].str.extract(regex).notnull()` into `df['text'].str.extractall(regex).notnull().groupby(level=0).max()`

output:

```
                                                text      labels
0  Kevin Lee has bought a Taylor Swift's CD and e...  Food,Music
1       The best burger in McDonald is cheeze buger.        Food
2  Kevin Lee is planning to watch the Big Bang Th...     Food,TV
```

Comment: Hey @mozway. Can I trouble you on a follow-up question? How do I do an ignore case on the labelling? Say on "Food": ["McDonald", "Five Guys", "KFC" ], I have a text like "Today we have a report from CNKFC". It's now labelling as "Food" on the stirng due to partial string matching. Is there a way I can put something into the dictionary and ignore the word "CNKFC" so the string don't get labelled as "Food"?

Comment: @codedancer you could add [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in your regex, such as `\bABC\b` will match only `ABC` but not `ABCD`

Comment: Hey @mozway, I have got an error message from a line of your solution - max()*topic_dict.keys()). The error message says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'bool' and 'dict_keys'. During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: AssertionError Traceback (most recent call last)". I think the solution works on Python (3.7) but now lower version. Any suggestion it can have a different way to overcome this line?